# Nginx: [warn] An upstream response is buffered to a temporary file

Tags: tomcat, nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I get many of these warnings in my `nginx/error.log`. It is only a warning and not an error, but is it something I should fix? Is it enabling for a DDOS attack? How would I fix it? I'm using Nginx on AWS Elastic Beanstalk as a proxy to Tomcat.

> 2018/11/25 22:01:14 [warn] 3402#0: *81345 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/6/12/0000002126 while reading upstream, client: 172.99.99.99, server: , request: "GET /fonts/font-600.woff2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/fonts/font-600.woff2", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/css/style.css"

Comment: This might help [over on SF.SE](https://serverfault.com/questions/587386/an-upstream-response-is-buffered-to-a-temporary-file#587432).